# NodeJS v12.18.1 SetInterval stops running after a few days

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, setinterval

I am using a setInterval function to send a ping every minute, problem is that after an arbitrary number of days,the setInteval callback no longer gets executed. I am aware of the issue that was fixed in v10.9.0 https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/22149, but this is is happening in version 12, and not after 25 days.

this is a simplified version of what I am using setInterval for:

```js
startPing() {
  console.log(`will start sending pings in 60 seconds`)
  this.pingInterval = setInterval(() => {

    console.log("sending ping", new Date())
    this.socket.write('ping');
    // if no response is recieved after whenToTimeut number of seconds, invoke timeout to try to reconnect.
    const whenToTimeOut = 30* 1000
    this.socket.setTimeout(whenToTimeOut);
  }, 60*1000)
}
```

After reading about the issues with setInterval I've decided to use node-cron for now, I know it uses setTimeout under the hood, but we also have a process running using it, and it doesn't stop even when the ping process stops.

What I am wondering is, has anyone faced this issue before, and has anyone figured out a way to replicate it (couldn't do it using [libfaketime](https://github.com/wolfcw/libfaketime)), because even if I use the node-cron package, I still wanna make sure that it's the setInterval that was causing the issue.

PS. I've tried to look for any possible resource leakage problem, but couldn't find any, and the process is running fine aside from the ping process stopping.

Comment: Why not make one single ping, and set it up as a true cron job at OS level, every minute?

Comment: Use system "Cron" jobs

Comment: @JeremyThille I am not sure if this could work, as I need to set a timeout for the socket depending on if a pong is received or not whenever a ping is sent, I also need to to perform some extra functionality before sending the pings, so node-cron I guess is just easier to integrate with the app.

Comment: Ah, indeed, if there's a socket involved, it's going to be much more complicated :/ I didn't notice it

Comment: @sojin same as above

Comment: @ThabetSabha No, you need to use Linux cron jobs to do this task, you can use 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron package. or if you are using ubuntu or linux you can run cron jobs there

Comment: @sojin, like I said in my original post, node-cron is what I will be using as it's easier to integrate with the app, thanks though, main reason for the post was to figure out if other people have encountered this, or if there is a problem with the way I'm using it.